# The named parameter onImageTaped isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement a functionality where if an image is clicked, then it should navigate to a new page. Below code was working perfectly until recently when it showed me a squiggly red error underneath the function `onImageTap`.

```
child: new Carousel(
                          boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                          images: list,
                          onImageTap: (imageIndex) {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                              new MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => new DishDetails(
                                    detail_name:
                                        snapshot.data[imageIndex].data["title"],
                                    detail_picture: snapshot
                                        .data[imageIndex].data["image"]),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          autoplay: false,
                          dotSize: 4.0,
                          indicatorBgPadding: 4.0,
                          animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                        )));
```

When I hover over the function, I get the following error message:

> The named parameter onImageTap isn't defined. Try correcting the name
>   to an existing named parameter or defining a new parameter with this
>   name

Can someone tell me how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned it was working earlier, so I believe you are using some 3rd party package which have `Carousel` widget and in one of its previous versions it had `onImageTap`, you unknowingly updated the plugin and they must have removed it or replaced it with something else.

**Solution:**

So, you can either use the previous version which had `onImageTap` property or use something else for it.

You may want to wrap your `Carousel` in a `GestureDetector` and handle `onTap` like:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Carousel(...)
)
```

Comment: I actually did not update any packages. 

With the solution you provided, I actually want onTap inside the carousel because the images are inside the carousel

Comment: This is their link: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_pro#-readme-tab-

I am using the earliest version.

Comment: How can that be true if you hadn't updated the package, something was working before but not now without you updating anything? And did you try the above solution, it should work, the images will receive `onTap`, please give it a try if you haven't already and I've never used this plugin on my own ever.